# Using Dart JS interop with ES6 classes

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop, dart-dev-compiler

JavaSscript:

```
class MyClass {

    constructor() {
        console.log("MyClass instance created");
        this.answer = 42;
    }
}

let example = new MyClass();
console.log(example.answer);
```

Dart:

```
@JS()
library interop_test;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
class MyClass {
  external int get answer;
  external set answer(int value);
}
```

Creating an instance of the the interop class `MyClass` as

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass();
```

results in:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: dart.global.MyClass is not a constructor

I've also tried to add a `external MyClass();` and `external factory MyClass();` to the `@JS()` annotated class, but got the same message. If I add `@anonymous` annotation to the interop class, the exception goes away, but I can't access instance members. (But I don't see why this would need the anonymous annotation)

I'm using `dart 2.0.0`, `angular 5.0.0`, `js 0.6.1+1` and `dartdevc` through `webdev`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally JS interop would rely on function hoisting to ensure that an old-style JS class was in scope. ES6 classes however aren't hoisted and aren't available where Dart expects them to be. There are several different ways you can make the class available to Dart:

#### Placing the class object on the window

This places the class in the same scope that a function definition would be hoisted to. In JavaScript:

```
class MyClass { ... }

window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

#### Creating a module object

You can also place the class in a sort of pseudo module or namespace. In JavaScript:

```
class MyClass { ... }
var myModule = { MyClass: MyClass };
```

Which is then accessible at `myModule.myClass` in Dart:

```
@JS('myModule.myClass')
class MyClass { ... }
```

Comment: Both suggestions worked just great! Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this implies manually editing the js library. This would require a local copy it if you were importing it in a script tag. Is there any other way that would not require doing so ?

Comment: I added window.Myclass = Myclass in my script file but I am getting error dart.global.Myclass is not a constructor.